# Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

Tags: objective-c, ios, three20

I'm going to paste the code below, then tell you what I've tried to determine from the code.

**If you're reading this quickly, start with the text right above the next code-block.**

```
- (void)tableViewDidLoadModel:(UITableView*)tableView {
self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
self.sections = [NSMutableArray array];

NSMutableDictionary *groups = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int c = 0;c < [_contacts.people count];c++) {
    NSDictionary *person = [_contacts.people objectAtIndex:c];
    NSString *name = [person objectForKey:@"fullName"];
    NSString *letter = [name substringToIndex:1];
    NSMutableArray *section = [groups objectForKey:letter];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - %@", name, [person objectForKey:@"index"], [person objectForKey:@"abId"]);
    if (!section) {
        section = [NSMutableArray array];
        [groups setObject:section forKey:letter];
    }

    TTTableItem *item = [ttItem itemWithText:name URL:[person objectForKey:@"index"]];
    [section addObject:item];
}
```

Someone else wrote this block of code. From what I can determine, they're trying to take the user's contacts and fill a `TableView`.

Now my real question has to do with that last line:

```
TTTableItem *item = [ttItem itemWithText:name URL:[person objectForKey:@"index"]];
    [section addObject:item];
```

This is using the Three20 framework. Apparently what the previous developer did was use `TTTableItem` to kind of get a pre-formatted `UITableViewCell`. (Hopefully I'm thinking right?)
I need to replace this line of code with something normal.
I've thought of just using `UITableViewCell`, but other than that I'm not really sure how to start?

Comment: UITableViewCell Seems right to me.  ***never*** use Three20 for anything worthwhile.

Comment: I agree with you 100% about Three20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-tableViewDidLoadModel:` is a method that comes from the TTTableViewDataSource protocol, so if you're trying to remove Three20 from your project, you've got more to do than just replace the TTTableItem.

[TTTableItem](http://api.Three20.info/interface_t_t_table_item.php) is a subclass of NSObject, and the only thing it seems to add is a `userInfo` property. To get rid of it, you could start by creating your own class with the same property.